# Get URL of Paginator next and previous CakePHP 2

Tags: cakephp, pagination

I'm using paginator on CakePHP 2. I already sent the paginator from the controller to the view. If I debug the next and prev methods of the paginator this is what I get:

```
debug($this->Paginator->next(null, null, array('class' => 'disabled')));
'<span class="next"><a href="/Project/Controller/method/127151/page:2" rel="next"></a></span>'
```

I need to do the pagination on a frame in the same page, so when the user click next or previous page, not all the page refresh, just the frame that I'm using to display the data. I will do that using the $.post method of Jquery, but I need the URL that the prev and next show within the href, not all the span and the other elements, something like *$this->Html->url provides*.

Someone know how can I retrieve the URL from the previous and next methods of the paginator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to get this resolved using the DOM methods of PHP:

```
    $htmlNext = $this->Paginator->next(null, null, array('class' => 'disabled')); //gets paginator next HTML tag
    $domNext = new DOMDocument();
    $domNext->loadHTML($htmlNext);
    $tagsNext = $domNext->getElementsByTagName('a');
    $theLinkNext = "";
    foreach ($tagsNext as $tag) 
    {
        $theLinkNext = $tag->getAttribute('href');
    }
```

Now on the $theLinkNext variable you have the URL for the next page, then you just call $.post of Jquery and use the URL to get the data:

```
var loadNotesPage = "<?php echo $theLinkNext ?>";
$.post(loadNotesPage, function (data) {
    $('#loading-notes').html(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try This way

```
$nextPage=$this->params->paging['MODELNAME']['nextPage']; // for users table MODELNAME User 
'<span class="next"><a href="/Project/Controller/method/127151/page:'.$nextPage.'" rel="next"></a></span>'
```

Answer (score 0):

`$this->Paginator->url()` By default returns a full pagination URL string for use in non-standard contexts (i.e. JavaScript). you can check out cakephp 2.x documentation  [here](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html) i hope this helps someone